# Use regex to find a string in an URL

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find the following string in a series of URL's

`?filters=categories`

The URL's like are:

```
www.domain.com/shoes?filters=categories
www.domain.com/clothes/design?filters=categories
www.domain.com/bags/designer/season?filters=categories
```

I've been looking here http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

I've tried `.?filters=categories` but it doesn't seem to work

What is the correct regex to find what I need?

Thanks

Comment: what language? Most language have robust URL/URI parsers that will do a better job then you can with a regular expression

Comment: actually, I'm using this program [link](http://www.sitesucker.us/archive/2.x/2.3.x/2.3/manuals/en/pgs/Paths.html) and it supports the use of regex to exclude certain URL's. I'm trying to get it to work but the regex's I've tried don't work..

Answer (score 1):

Escape the special character `?` to make it a literal.

```
\?filters=categories$
```

Answer (score 1):

`?` is a special regex character meaning "0-1 of the preceding expression". You need to escape it to make it a literal:

```
\?filters=categories
```

If you want to extract the filters parameter value, use this regex:

```
(?<=\?filters=).*?(?=$|&)
```

This expression would match `categories` in your example.

Comment: Your regex won't match the whole value field if it contains any URL-encoded characters, if you use `\b`.

Comment: @Cairnarvon hmmm i was taking a shortcut - how's that look now?

Answer (score 0):

```
/\?filters=categories$/
```

But I doubt if regex is the solution for your problem. Matching static strings can be a lot faster done with other functions.

Comment: can someone explain the -1, would like to hear how I can provide better answers

Answer (score 0):

What you're probably looking for is:

```
\?filters=categories$
```

That will match a literal question mark followed by `filters=categories` at the end of a string.

If there's any chance the URL's [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) can contain additional data, though, and you still want to match in that case, you should use a proper URL-parsing library instead. Or possibly use this instead:

```
(?<=\?|\?.*&)filters=categories(?=&|$)
```

That matches `filters=categories` at any point in a query string, using lookarounds.

Answer (score 0):

**(\?filters=categories)**

This regex will match exactly what you want ...

http://www.regexbuddy.com/ this is more helpful

Comment: this will not match: `www.domain.com/foo/?filters=categories`

Comment: @M42 understood , thank you. Is that ok now

Comment: Close. You'd keep the word boundary `\b` at the end.